# Java Converting date to epoch value produces false output

Tags: java, linux, date, ubuntu, epoch

I am trying to convert the below date time string object  into a unix epoch timestamp value. However, when i run the program i notice that it generates an epoch value of 1404461110000 which when i check on my ubuntu unix machine is Wed Aug  7 18:06:40 However in reality i am passing July 04 2014-07-04 04:05:10. I have a time zone of America/Toronto on my ubuntu machine but I don't think it should matter here ?

Java code:

```
            long epoch = 0;
            String str = "2014-07-04 04:05:10";   // UTC

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date datenew = df.parse(str);
            epoch = datenew.getTime();

            System.out.println(epoch); // prints 1404461110000
```

Ubuntu Linux 14.04

```
date -d@1404461110000
```

displays= Wed Aug  7 18:06:40 EDT 46475

Comment: You've not accounted for the time zone, which `Date` will apply when printing the text...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you're not dealing with a [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) when calling `getTime()` in Java. Unix timestamps are expressed in **seconds** since the epoch, while the values you're getting from Java are **milliseconds** since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) (Jan 01 1970), hence the difference.

It would have to be:

```
epoch = datenew.getTime() / 1000;
```

This should get you at least a couple of 10000 years closer. If you still see a difference after that, it's timezone-related, and can be accommodated for by specifying the timezone on your `DateFormat` instance.

Comment: or 44461 years closer ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Is that value with the timezone taken into account? ;-)

Comment: as per OP `displays= Wed Aug 7 18:06:40 EDT 46475`

Comment: I never realized this thanks a lot indeed i am 44461 closer now :-)

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "2014-07-04 04:05:10"; // UTC

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str, dtf);
        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        Instant instant = zdtUtc.toInstant();
        long epochMillis = instant.toEpochMilli();
        long epochSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(epochMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println(epochSeconds);

        // Corresponding date-time in America/Toronto
        ZonedDateTime zdtToronto = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto"));
        System.out.println(zdtToronto);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1404446710
2014-07-04T00:05:10-04:00[America/Toronto]
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Some important notes:**

1. [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) specifies seconds since the Epoch.
2. We should avoid performing calculations ourselves if there is an OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box) API available for it e.g. [`TimeUnit#convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Java that the timestamp is UTC, not just add a comment about it.

```
long epoch = 0;
String str = "2014-07-04 04:05:10";   // UTC

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // assume UTC
Date datenew = df.parse(str);
epoch = datenew.getTime();

System.out.println(epoch);
```

Comment: Yep, that will make `Wed Aug 7 18:06:40 EDT 46475` become to `2014` wont it?

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

FYI, here is the same kind of code but done in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4. The new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time) could be used in a similar manner.

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either of the two libraries mentioned above.

### Example Code

Your input string is close to standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, but not quite, missing the `T` in the middle and an offset from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Joda-Time has a built-in formatter for parsing/generating in ISO 8601. So rather than define our own formatter, let's tweak the input String a bit, inserting the `T`.

```
String inputRaw = "2014-07-04 04:05:10";   // UTC
String input = inputRaw.replace( " ", "T" ); // Convert to standard ISO 8601 format.
```

Then we will tell the DateTime constructor to parse the String as being in UTC (zero offset). Unlike java.util.Date, a DateTime knows its own assigned time zone.

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( input, DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Easy to adjust to Toronto time, for fun or for debugging/sanity-check.

```
DateTime dateTimeToronto = dateTimeUtc.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Toronto" ) );
```

Like java.util.Date, Joda-Time internally tracks time as a number of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) since the Unix epoch (beginning of 1970) in UTC. That means using a 64-bit `long` rather than the usual 32-bit `int`. (By the way, java.time tracks [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).) So if we need seconds-since-unix-epoch, divide by one thousand.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = dateTimeUtc.getMillis();  // Use a "long", not "int".
long secondsSinceEpoch = ( millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000L );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeToronto: " + dateTimeToronto );
System.out.println( "millisecondsSinceEpoch: " + millisecondsSinceEpoch );
System.out.println( "secondsSinceEpoch: " + secondsSinceEpoch );
```

When run.

```
input: 2014-07-04T04:05:10
dateTimeUtc: 2014-07-04T04:05:10.000Z
dateTimeToronto: 2014-07-04T00:05:10.000-04:00
millisecondsSinceEpoch: 1404446710000
secondsSinceEpoch: 1404446710
```